# How to change %Hh%M to %M form in R CSV?

Tags: csv, r

I am thinking how you can dynamically change the time duration form (etc `11h11` resembling `%Hh%M`) to minute form like `%M`. 
I think it is best to maintain the original data form used by *EMFIT-QS* device. 
Data

```
Name,Time_duration
Leo,11h11
```

Code

```
DF <- read.csv("/home/masi/Documents/Data/data.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
str(DF)
```

Outut

```
$ Time_duration         : Factor w/ 1 level 11h11",..
```

My proposal

1. Change data time duration to minutes where second column for specifying units to avoid confusion because non-standard units

   ```
   Name,Time_duration
   -, min
   Leo,671
   ```
2. Do not change the standard fields given by `%Hh%M`, I would really like to programmatically convert all fields manually to minute presentation `%M`

R: 3.3.3

Comment: Can you preprocess with another language, or does it all need to be in R ?

Comment: @ivanivan Answer can be about another language. It can help to see the other side of the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom `colClasses` function - as described in [Specify custom Date format for colClasses argument in read.table/read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13022441/4440445)

To illustrate; given

```
$ cat file.csv 
Name,Time_duration
Leo,11h11
```

then in `R`

```
> setClass('myTime')
> 
> setAs('character','myTime', function(from) {
+ x <- as.POSIXlt(from, format='%Hh%M')
+ return (x$hour*60 + x$min)
+ })
> 
> data <- read.csv2(file='file.csv', sep=',', dec='.', header=TRUE, 
+ colClasses=c('character','myTime'))
> 
> data
  Name Time_duration
1  Leo           671
>
```

Comment: Confirmed, this approach works!